# OpenAccess nuget package and Cannot find resource EntitiesModel.rlinq embedded in assembly exception

Tags: telerik, nuget-package, telerik-open-access, openaccess

We want to remove the necessity of installing OpenAccess on the client and build machine and plan to do that using OpenAccess nuget packages.
I've been following [the guide](http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/developers-guide/integrating-openaccess-orm-in-your-solution/developer-guide-integration-using-oa-nuget-packages) and installed OpenAccess.CodeFirst nuget packages for all projects in solution which deal with ORM.

Unfortunately, I receive the infamous exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'XXXl' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Cannot find resource EntitiesModel.rlinq embedded in assembly
```

I've checked all the steps from this [article](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/orm/general/handling-error-cannot-find-resource.aspx) but I'm still getting the same error. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the Telerik OpenAccess ORM Nuget Packages provide support for the code first approach, by default settings are optimized for [fluent mapping](http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/getting-started/getting-started-fluent-mapping-overview) and only fluent mapping models will be enhanced. In order to use different type of mapping (Xml mapping or Attributes mapping) you need to enable it following those steps:

1. Unload the project containing your model and open the project file
   for editing.
2. Enable xml mapping by adding true in
   the first PropertyGroup of the project file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ...>
  ...
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <UseXmlMapping>true</UseXmlMapping>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Additionally you can find an alternative approach for using Telerik OpenAccess ORM without installation described by this documentation article -  http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/developers-guide/integrating-openaccess-orm-in-your-solution/external-tools-howto-integrate-enhancer-msbuild .